# trac-admin hotcopy not working when run from crontab

Tags: cron, trac

I've recently updated Trac from 0.11.4 to 0.12.2. I'm using the following shell script to backup Trac installation:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=/root/backup/trac/
NAME=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M`
cd $DIR
trac-admin /var/trac/projects/myproject/ hotcopy ./temp
tar -zcf TRAC_$NAME.tar.gz -C $DIR/temp .
rm -rf ./temp
```

It works ok when run from console, but the cronjob fails with following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/trac-admin", line 5, in <module>
   from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2675, in <module>
   parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 552, in resolve
   raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Trac==0.11.4
tar: /root/backup/trac//temp: Cannot chdir: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Why does it work when run manually and not when from crontab? Why does it look for 0.11.4 version of Trac if I use 0.12.2 now?

Trac was installed and upgraded with `easy_install`.

Comment: It is recommended to use full paths in cron jobs. Otherwise, you may end up calling the wrong script or program. Also, you need to make sure that you are executing your script under the same user.

Comment: Thank you very much, that actually solved my problem. I've been using `/usr/bin/trac-admin` instead of `/usr/local/bin/trac-admin` all the time :(

Comment: I posted it as answer. You can accept it so that others can benefit from this port.

Comment: Additionally, you are getting an error for an invalid destination.  Prior to the trac-admin call you should have some error handing to create the destination if needed. `if [ ! -d ./temp ]; then mkdir -p ./temp; fi` This looks like Hell with the formatting lost but hopefully you get my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommended to use full paths in cron jobs. Otherwise, you may end up calling the wrong script or program.

Also, you need to make sure that you are executing your script under the same user.